# VB.NET Adding New Lines with SMTP Email

Tags: vb.net, smtp, newline

I'm using VB.NET to send an email. 
An example of the email might look like this:

Name: (Name) 
Email Address: (Email Address) 
Phone Number: (Phone Number)

The following code snippet below works. It just puts too much spacing between lines. I've tried getting rid of System.Environment.NewLine but then my lines don't format properly anymore.

I also tried not using a StringBuilder and it also didn't format properly as well.

```
'Email Generation ----------------------------------------------------
 Dim builder As New StringBuilder
 builder.AppendLine("Name: " + Name + System.Environment.NewLine")
 builder.AppendLine("Email Address: " + EmailAddress+ System.Environment.NewLine")
 builder.AppendLine("Phone Number: " + PhoneNumber+ System.Environment.NewLine")

 emailBody = builder.ToString
```

Any suggestions would definitely help!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the additionnal spacing is due to a new line in the message and not just some styling?

Comment: Also, the " in your exemple are all messed up

Comment: Is it plain text or HTML formated?

Comment: I tried inserting <br> tags and that didn't work. I'm guessing it's plain text formatted. I'm not 100% sure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using html format rather than plain text try the following

```
Dim fullName As String = "Karen Payne"
Dim emailAddress As String = "payne@gmail.com"
Dim phoneNumber As String = "555-334-1111"
Dim content =
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name: <%= fullName %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email address: <%= emailAddress %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Phone number: <%= phoneNumber %></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
```

If this still has too much space for you let me know.

Comment: I was able to change it to an html format and it worked out for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the encoding right, and if you're not using < br > then IsBodyHtml needs to be set to false. Here's a simple example:

```
Dim server As New SmtpClient
Dim email As New MailMessage
server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
server.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("x", "x")
server.Port = 25
server.EnableSsl = False
server.Host = "x"

email.From = New MailAddress("x")
email.To.Add("x")
email.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
Dim s = "Name: " + vbNewLine + "Email: " + vbNewLine + "Phone"
email.Body = s
server.Send(email)
```

I replaced all the credentials/addresses with "x"